# Pregel algorithms

Tags: graph

There are a plenty of [Pregel](http://www-bd.lip6.fr/ens/grbd2011/extra/SIGMOD10_pregel.pdf) implementations

- Apache Giraph    http://incubator.apache.org/giraph/
- Phoebus  https://github.com/xslogic/phoebus
- Bagel    https://github.com/mesos/spark/pull/48 Apache
- Hama http://incubator.apache.org/hama/
- Signal-Collect   http://code.google.com/p/signal-collect/

But I couldn't find much algorithm examples implemented for Pregel frameworks. There are always shortest-path, page rank, but not more than that.

Could you point on any other algorithms implemented for Pregel frameworks?

Comment: Yes, the Google Pregel paper describes a couple more in addition to shortest-path and PageRank: 'bipartite matching' and 'semi-clustering', but, for example, these have not been implemented in Apache Giraph yet.

Comment: The hama community is actively involved in writing all new kinds of algorithms on top of bsp. Please have a look at hama examples and ml modules.